# ListView Selector on Specific Element Within ListView View

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having a problem where I want each subchild of a view for a listview to have it's own custom selector. There are a few solutions already but none of them seem to work at all for me. Here's my xml for the listview and individual view. Does anyone know specifically what I need to do? Right now If I can get show_group_actions and action_calendar to have separate selectors working I'd be quite happy...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_show_group_actions"
        style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Row"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_name"
            style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Row.TextView"
            android:text="@string/label_my_groups"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Group.OpenClose"
            >

            <me.magneto.groups.views.IconView
                android:id="@+id/action_show_group_actions_arrow"
                style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Group.OpenClose.Arrow"
                android:text="@string/icon_chevron_down"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_calendar"
        style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Group.Row"
        >

        <me.magneto.groups.views.IconView
            style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Group.IconView"
            android:text="@string/icon_calendar"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/AppTheme.NavigationDrawer.Row.TextView"
            android:text="@string/label_calendar"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_list_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:background="@color/navigation_primary_background"
    />
```

[image: Each row has a unique selector, xml it's a block]

Comment: can you post an image it look like right and what you want it to be

Comment: Will get a screenshot up in a second....., each row should have a unique selector but in the xml, like above, it's grouped under one linearlayout.

Comment: I forgot to mention, what ends up happening is like all of the rows share one selector so it looks like all of the rows are selected because they are grouped together